# Mysql can't connect from another pc using ip

Tags: c#, mysql

I am making small c# application which uses mysql server. I have on one pc mysql server and developing program(on same pc) and when I connect by ip to that computer(which has mysql server) I can access with no problem. But when I transfer that same program to another pc(who does not have) it can't access to mysql server on first pc. I opened port  tcp and udp 3306 on firewall but still can't connect from second pc.
My connection string is: `string connect = "server=192.168.x.xx;port=3306;database=my;uid=root;pwd=passs;";`

I searched for my.ini and can't find bind-address. my.ini looks like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/107777491/my.ini
my.ini location is:C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini

and also I did this command in mysql command shell:

```
GRAND ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passs';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```